# How to use excel formula to highlight 3 closest values from range

Tags: excel, excel-formula

```
  A
```

1)  0.218967921
2)  0.02111355
3)  **0.145493415**
4)  **0.151092791**
5)  **0.15407891**
6)  0.178046392
7)  0.11408411

I need to Highlight number 0.145493415 ,0.151092791,0.15407891 (column 3,4,5) which is closest in the list.

Comment: What would you want to do if the list contains duplicates? e.g. if you changed the value at 2) so that it equals the value at 3) what would you want highlighted then?

Comment: Hi Barry, This list is not containing any duplicates.

Comment: What if 8) was 0.14? Then the two smallest differences when sorted would belong to two separate pairs of numbers. Maybe you mean the 3 consecutive numbers n1<n2<n3 such that n2-n1 + n3-n2 is as small as possible? Then this boils down to finding the smallest value of n3-n1 and would be easy to do with a helper column (A3-A1, A4-A2 ...).

Comment: Correct Tom. I need n2 - n1 + n3 - n2 as small as possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you have unsorted data in `A1:A7` without duplicates, and the "3 closest values" are those where the difference between smallest and largest (of the three) is the smallest difference of **any** three values in that range, then you can use this formula in conditional formatting

`=ABS(RANK(A1,A$1:A$7)-MATCH(MIN(LARGE(A$1:A$7,ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&COUNT(A$1:A$7)-2)))-LARGE(A$1:A$7,ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&COUNT(A$1:A$7)-2))+2)),LARGE(A$1:A$7,ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&COUNT(A$1:A$7)-2)))-LARGE(A$1:A$7,ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&COUNT(A$1:A$7)-2))+2),0)-1)<=1`

It's rather complex but it can equally be applied to any sized list of values, even containing blanks or text values in the range

If there's more than one set of 3 with the same "spreadover" then the formula only highlights the **largest** set of values.

See [this example](https://www.dropbox.com/s/li4ceio1dmvesxn/Closest3.xlsx?dl=0)

Comment: What can I say? Except that if any of us mere mortals wished to learn from this by stepping through it as a stand-alone formula, it would be entered as an array formula at the top of a spare column and pulled down.

Answer (score 1):

Here for completeness is my answer to the much simpler problem of highlighting the nearest three adjacent numbers in the original data but it's only valid if data are all in ascending or descending order so needs further work:-

```
=OR(
AND(ROW()<=5,ABS(A3-A1)=MIN(ABS(A$3:A$7-A$1:A$5))),
AND(ROW()<=6,IFERROR(ABS(A2-OFFSET(A1,-1,0))=MIN(ABS(A$3:A$7-A$1:A$5)),FALSE)),
AND(ROW()<=7,IFERROR(ABS(A1-OFFSET(A1,-2,0))=MIN(ABS(A$3:A$7-A$1:A$5)),FALSE))
)
```

Limitations: Data must be in ascending or descending order. All cells in range A1:A7 have to contain numbers. Treats empty cells as zero.

---

The basic formula to highlight the first cell in a group of three nearest cells without assuming that the data are in order would be:-

```
=ABS(A2-A1)+ABS(A3-A2)=MIN(ABS(A$2:A$6-A$1:A$5)+ABS(A$3:A$7-A$2:A$6))
```

The formula to highlight three cells would then be:-

```
=OR(
AND(ROW()<=5,ABS(A2-A1)+ABS(A3-A2)=MIN(ABS(A$2:A$6-A$1:A$5)+ABS(A$3:A$7-A$2:A$6))),
AND(ROW()<=6,IFERROR(ABS(A1-OFFSET(A1,-1,0))+ABS(A2-A1)=MIN(ABS(A$2:A$6-A$1:A$5)+ABS(A$3:A$7-A$2:A$6)),FALSE)),
AND(ROW()<=7,IFERROR(ABS(OFFSET(A2,-2,0)-OFFSET(A1,-2,0))+ABS(A1-OFFSET(A2,-2,0))=MIN(ABS(A$2:A$6-A$1:A$5)+ABS(A$3:A$7-A$2:A$6)),FALSE))
)
```

Limitations: All cells in range A1:A7 have to contain numbers. Treats empty cells as zero.

---

In response to the question of whether it only works for exactly seven cells, here is a version of the  formula that works for any block of numbers starting at A1 and followed by a block of empty cells within the range A1:A1000:-

```
=OR(
AND(ROW()<=COUNT(A$1:A$1000)-2,ABS(A2-A1)+ABS(A3-A2)=MIN(IF(ROW(A$3:A$1000)<=COUNT(A$1:A$1000),ABS(A$2:A$999-A$1:A$998)+ABS(A$3:A$1000-A$2:A$999)))),
AND(ROW()<=COUNT(A$1:A$1000)-1,IFERROR(ABS(A1-OFFSET(A1,-1,0))+ABS(A2-A1)=MIN(IF(ROW(A$3:A$1000)<=COUNT(A$1:A$1000),ABS(A$2:A$999-A$1:A$998)+ABS(A$3:A$1000-A$2:A$999))),FALSE)),
AND(ROW()<=COUNT(A$1:A$1000),IFERROR(ABS(OFFSET(A2,-2,0)-OFFSET(A1,-2,0))+ABS(A1-OFFSET(A2,-2,0))=MIN(IF(ROW(A$3:A$1000)<=COUNT(A$1:A$1000),ABS(A$2:A$999-A$1:A$998)+ABS(A$3:A$1000-A$2:A$999))),FALSE))
)
```

Limitations: The block of numbers must not contain any empty cells or text.

If there are two groups with the same least spread, both will be highlighted.

These formulae can be used in conditional formatting or as stand-alone array formulae.

[image]

Comment: Hi Tom, So does this formula works for any numbers of records in column A or only for 7 records as shown in question?

Comment: The short answer is that it only works for 7 records and you'd have to modify it for more records. It's not the sort of formula where you can put A:A to process a whole column unfortunately. Guess I need to change it so it ignores blanks then you could put in a bigger range than the actual data to allow for expansion.

Comment: Er, I'm not sure, but yours is certainly a brilliant answer and useful to other people.

Comment: Even if the requirement is to highlight 3 consecutive cells, does your answer here fulfill the requirement? A1:A3 might be deemed to be the closest if A1 is close to A3 but that takes no account of A2, assuming values in the range 0 to 1 what's to stop A1 being 0.1 and A3 being 0.11 but A2 = 0.99?

Comment: True, it only works if a1<a2<a3  or a1>a2>a3 as mentioned in my earlier comment. I was coming originally from the idea that the data would be sorted first but it's clear that the sample data isn't although the section of interest is pretty monotonic.

Comment: So it would give a spurious result of you had a run like .1,.2,.1. I should delete my answer or at least put a health warning on it. Won't have much chance to look at it for next couple of days so please feel free to put up a Barry special that looks for min(abs(A2-A1)+abs(A3-A2))  etc

Answer (score 0):

You changed the list!  First, you have to sort the list from smallest to largest.  Then:

In cell B2 put `=A2-A1`

In cell B3 put `=A3-A2`

In cell B4 put `=A4-A3`

In cell B5 put `=A5-A4`

etc.

In cell b10, calculate the first closest pair: `=min(B1:B8)`
In cell B11, calculate the row number of the first closest pair:`=Match(B10,B1:B8,0)`

In cell C2, put `=if(row(C2)=b$11, 9999, B2)`
copy down to cell C9
In cell C10, calculate the SECOND closest pair: `=min(C1:C8)`
In cell C11, calculate the row number of the SECOND closest pair:`=Match(C10,C1:C8,0)`

copy column c to column d and e

column e will have 9999 in the lowest three values
Highlight A1:A10, sELECT conditional formatting, enter formula "$e1=9999"

Comment: Thank you for your prompt reply. I am actually looking for formula which I can use in conditional formatting to highlight 3 most closest values from list of values.

Comment: Is it necessarily without sorting?

Comment: Actually there may not be such a thing as the "3 most closest values from list of value."  Consider this list:  1
2
6
9
14
16.  My answer above gives you the "3 most closest pairs," although it only gives you the lower value of each pair.  The higher value is = 1+ Match(C10,C1:C8,0)